# How can I check if a String contains non-KSC5601 letter or not in Java/Kotlin?

Tags: android, unicode, fonts, cjk

I am checking Korean letters and I've tried with `[^ㄱ-ㅎ|ㅏ-ㅣ|가-힣*$]`.
For Number, English, Korean. I am using `^[0-9a-zA-Zㄱ-ㅎ|ㅏ-ㅣ|가-힣]*$`.

I am using DX Musical Font. And it doesn't support all the letters because it is KSC5601 type.
I'd like to check if this font can show a specific letter in a String.

For example, if I type `숮`, `쀍`, it shows nothing. And I'd like to show toast message that the String contains non-KSC5601 type which can't show in the EditText or TextView to write again.

```
et_answer.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher {
    override fun beforeTextChanged(p0: CharSequence?, p1: Int, p2: Int, p3: Int) {
    }

    override fun onTextChanged(p0: CharSequence?, p1: Int, p2: Int, p3: Int) {
    }

    override fun afterTextChanged(p0: Editable?) {
        if (!Pattern.matches(TextUtil.KoEnNumRex, et_answer.text.toString())) {
            MyToast(this@MyActivity).makeText("Only Korean, English, Number are available.")
            return
        }
    }
}
```

It'd be great if it can show the index of the incorrect letters.

Answer (score 0):

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private EditText editText;

    private String CharacterSet = "~#^|$%&*!FGHIJKLMOPTWXYZ";

    private InputFilter filter = new InputFilter() {

        @Override
        public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end, Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {

            if (source != null && !CharacterSet.contains(("" + source))) {
                return "";
            }
            return null;
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        editText.setFilters(new InputFilter[] { filter });
    }

}
```

here we are defineing a valid character set and only allowing that as a input

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/nameText"
    android:layout_width="177dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:digits="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ" />
```

the same thing can be done in layout too

if you inplement InputFilter this way

```
InputFilter typeFilter = new InputFilter() {
        @Override
        public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end, Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {
            Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[a-zA-Z|\u4e00-\u9fa5]+");
            Matcher m = p.matcher(source.toString());
            if (!m.matches()) return "";
            return null;
        }
    };
```

where **\u4e00-\u9fa5**  this is range of unicode for chinese letters similar could be done if you find range of unicode for korean

Comment: Well, this doesn't check KSC5601 type.

Comment: add that character set in allowed list

Comment: what character? and where is allowed list?

Comment: the character set arrayy or the android digit attribute

Comment: well.. You don't know Korean. It has more than two thousand set.